# Multiple app output directories required for Vite Vue 3 setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have 2 Vue 3 apps configured using Vite having 2 different entry points. They are integrated in a bigger project and uses the build script of package.json to generate auto build with watch.

I need 2 different output folders also for the 2 different Vue 3 apps above mapped to their inputs. But I am unable to get separated output for the 2 Vue apps and they are being merged into one output folder. How to keep 2 different output directories and get the outputs of Vue apps therein as mapped by inputs?

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app1: 'path/to/main-app1.js',
        app2: 'path/to/main-app2.js',
      },
      output: {
        // Output for app1
        app1: {
          dir: 'dist/app1',
        },
        // Output for app2
        app2: {
          dir: 'dist/app2',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` and `output` options under `rollupOptions` are not designed to map different entry points to different output directories. Instead, they are used to specify the entry point and the output directory for the entire build process. This is why your two vue are being merged into one output folder, you can also refer [here.](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/1736)

If so, to achieve a separate output directories for each vue, you need to run vite multiple times with different config. for each app and this can be done by creating separate `vite.config.js` files for each app and then running the vite build command for each configuration.

In first app named `vite.config.app1.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

  export default defineConfig({
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        input: 'path/to/main-app1.js',
        output: {
          dir: 'dist/app1',
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

In the second app named `vite.config.app2.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

  export default defineConfig({
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        input: 'path/to/main-app2.js',
        output: {
          dir: 'dist/app2',
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Then, you need to update the scripts section in `package.json` to run the vite  command for each configuration.

```
"scripts": {
    "build:app1": "vite build --config vite.config.app1.js",
    "build:app2": "vite build --config vite.config.app2.js",
    "build": "npm run build:app1 && npm run build:app2"
  }
```

Now, when you run `npm run build`, it will build each app separately and output the results to the specified directories.

*This approach requires you to manage multiple vite configurations and build processes, which may increase the complexity of your project. But, for me, it is currently the most straightforward way to achieve it.

Comment: I also had -w in the package.json script to watch the changes during development. But with this I am not able to run the combined npm run build as it remains at app1 watch and does not go to app2 at all. Can you please add to it? Here is the example:  
 "build:app1": "vite build --mode development --config vite.config.app1.js -w",
"build:app2": "vite build --mode development --config vite.config.app2.js -w",
"build": "npm run build:app1 && npm run build:app2"

Comment: Never Mind. I achieved the above using npm-run-all package :)